# Django - context processors in the view?

Tags: python, django

Context processors in Django usually allow for a variable to be accessed by all templates. How do I access this variable in the views.py (backend) code?

Here is what I have tried:

```
def index(request):
    request_context = RequestContext(request)
    center =  request_context.get("center")
```

But I get "none" for the center variable.

And in the context processor code:

```
def center(request):
return {'center': '123'}
```

I have added the context processor's "center" function to the context processor list in settings.

Comment: Have you added you context processor in settings within `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` (if you are on Django < 1.8) or within `TEAMPLATES['OPTIONS']['context_processors']` (Django >= 1.8)?

Comment: I added it in the TEMPLATES -> OPTIONS -> context_processors list in settings.

Comment: Hmm it should work, make sure your custom context processor is after `django.template.context_processors.request`?

Comment: Still doesn't work...

Answer (score -1):

Use `decorators` instead of `context_processors`. It will be really very simple for you.
In `views.py` use `@csrf_exempt` before function from which you want to take a variable and use `{% csrf_token %}` on the end of a line in the template where you want to use that variable.
[Official documentation on csrf decorators](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/_modules/django/views/decorators/csrf/)

If you need to see an example then check out [this](https://github.com/vineetjai/DjangoProject-article/tree/master/article). Here in  template/add_comment.html and views.py is using decorators.

***NOTE***:- you need to import csrf_exempt in views.py before using it like:-
`from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I'm wondering how to use these variables in the views.py code, not in the template code.

Comment: You have to change in both views.py and in template to make it work.